# Which file do edit the cart.php?target=search&mode=search in xcart?

Tags: php, x-cart

Am newbie in x cart,In my analysis cart.php means front-end search file in

x cart/Xlite/Controller/Customer/Search.php (Target name in Class name of the file) But am given echo in below classname or empty file it does not any changes in cart.php?target=search&mode=search this url.Please give me solution for which file do edit for search.

Which file do edit the cart.php?target=search&mode=search in xcart,

How view page will be render in xcart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see any changes applied to the classes/ folder you either have to "Re-deploy the store" on the System settings -> Cache management page or enable developer mode.

Find "etc/config.php" file inside the X-Cart root folder and set the "developer_mode" option to "On". After that, any change to the code will be applied instantly.

Also, I highly recommended doing changes to the code in custom module. See more here - http://devs.x-cart.com/en/getting_started/.